# CSS style div3 differently if div1 and div2 don't exist

Tags: html, css

If a user is signed up to my site, in their login area I have 3 divs as follows:

```
<div id="psts-cancel-link" class="psts-cancel-link"></div>
<div class="psts-receipt-link"></div>
<div id="psts-signup-another"></div>
```

These divs all have a width of 32% and sit inline with each other.

```css
#psts-cancel-link {
  background: white;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 32%;
  min-height: 270px;
  float: left;
}
.psts-receipt-link {
  background: white;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 270px;
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#psts-signup-another {
  background: white;
  padding: 1em;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 32%;
  min-height: 270px;
  float: left;
}
```

When a user is not signed up, only one of the divs displays:

```
<div id="psts-signup-another"></div>
```

Is it possible to change the styling of this so that it's width is 100% when div1 and div2 aren't displayed?

So far I have tried this, but with no success:

```
#psts-cancel-link ~ .psts-receipt-link ~ #psts_existing_info #psts-signup-another {
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: where is `#psts_existing_info` in your markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Table Layout Implementation**

Use a `table` layout. Specify `display: table` on the parent and `display: table-cell` on the child elements.

```css
#psts-cancel-link {
  background: tomato;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
  min-height: 270px;
  display: table-cell;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.psts-receipt-link {
  background: lightblue;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 270px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#psts-signup-another {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 1em;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  min-height: 270px;
  display: table-cell;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
Logged in
<div class="container">
  <div id="psts-cancel-link"></div>
  <div class="psts-receipt-link"></div>
  <div id="psts-signup-another"></div>
</div>
Logged out
<div class="container">

  <div id="psts-signup-another"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Flexbox Layout Implementation**

You can also use flexbox which expands and shrinks the child items according to the parent container.

```css
#psts-cancel-link {
  background: tomato;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
  min-height: 270px;
  flex: 1;
}
.psts-receipt-link {
  background: lightblue;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 270px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
}
#psts-signup-another {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 1em;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  min-height: 270px;
  flex: 1;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
Logged in
<div class="container">
  <div id="psts-cancel-link"></div>
  <div class="psts-receipt-link"></div>
  <div id="psts-signup-another"></div>
</div>
Logged out
<div class="container">

  <div id="psts-signup-another"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `:first-child` if it's indeed the only child in the second case.

```
#psts-signup-another:first-child {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `adjacent` selector. Have a look at the following snippet:

```css
#psts-signup-another {padding: 5px; background: #f99;}
div + div + #psts-signup-another {padding: 5px; background: #99f;}
```

```html
<h2>Div when three divs are present</h2>
<div class="theDivs">
  <div id="psts-cancel-link" class="psts-cancel-link"></div>
  <div class="psts-receipt-link"></div>
  <div id="psts-signup-another"></div>
</div>
<h2>Div when three divs are not present</h2>
<div class="theDivs">
  <div id="psts-signup-another"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use another container div with a new class when user logout.

Logged:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="psts-cancel-link" class="psts-cancel-link"></div>
    <div class="psts-receipt-link"></div>
    <div id="psts-signup-another"></div>
</div>
```

Logout:

```
<div class="container logout">
    <div id="psts-cancel-link" class="psts-cancel-link"></div>
    <div class="psts-receipt-link"></div>
    <div id="psts-signup-another"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container.logout > div {
    display:none;
}
.container.logout > .psts-signup-another {
    display:block;
}
```